# How can I make the script that counts which number occurred most often and counts how many times do each of the 10 random numbers occur

Tags: java, arrays, count

To explain about the program that I am making, it is program that asks the user how many times he would like his coin to flip. In this program, the coin of the head is even, and the odd is the tail.

I created a script that randomizes numbers from 1 to 10 based on the number you entered. And also I've made the script that how many odd and even numbers had come out, but I don't know how to make a script that shows how many times do each of the 10 random numbers occur and which number occurred most often.

Here is the script that I have made:

```
import java.util.*;

public class GreatCoinFlipping {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("How many times do you want to flip the coin? : ");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int amount = sc.nextInt();

        int[] arrNum = new int[amount];
        int even = 0, odd = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < amount ; i++) {
            arrNum[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
            System.out.println(arrNum[i]);
            if (arrNum[i] % 2 == 0) even++;
            else                    odd++;
        }//end for
        System.out.println("Head: " + even + ", Tail: " + odd);
    }//end main
    
}//end class
```

What I am expecting on this script that that I want to make the script that shows how many times do each of the 10 random numbers occur and which number occurred most often and I want to make it by the count method. But the ramdon number part has to be in array method. Can someone please help me with this problem?

Comment: Java and JavaScript are two _different_ programming languages. Don't add the JavaScript tag to Java questions.

Comment: Not sure how is the java way to do this, but you could create a Map object which stores the occurence of the number and increment it each time the randomized number appears.

Answer (score 0):

To keep track of the random number you generate you can use a array. The array starts out as all 0's and is of size 10 (because there are 10 numbers between 0-9).

```java
int size = 10;
int numbers_counter[] = new int[size];

// initialize the values
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    numbers_counter[i] = 0;
}

// count some random numbers
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    numbers_counter[(int)(Math.random() * size)] += 1;
}

// print how many times each number accured
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    System.out.println("" + i + " occured: " + numbers_counter[i] + " times");
}
```

You can apply this method to your code.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but I'm really sorry that I still don't understand.... what I want is to know how to make program that counts which number occurred most often from the random numbers that I made, and counts how many times do each of the 10 random numbers occur also from random number program that I made. And those two has to be make by count method.

Answer (score 0):

The `arrNum` variable will contain an array of all occurences of each number. So if you want to count, for example, how many times 4 occurred in this, you can do this:

```
Arrays.stream(arrNum).filter(n -> n == 4).count()
```

For 7 you can do this:

```
Arrays.stream(arrNum).filter(n -> n == 7).count()
```

And you can do the same for other digits (1 to 10).

This would be a simple/straight-forward way of doing it. You can also improve it by creating a method that returns this count:

```
public static int getCount(int[] arr, int num) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr).filter(n -> n == num).count();
}
```

And then call this in a loop:

```
for(int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
    System.out.println("Count for " + i + ": " + getCount(arrNum, i));
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but I'm really sorry that I still don't understand.... what I want is to know how to make program that counts which number occurred most often from the random numbers that I made, and counts how many times do each of the 10 random numbers occur also from random number program that I made. And those two has to be make by count method.